# broadcasting the 'computer information' to all the computers that have the FOO application installed and are connected to internet

Tags: java, p2p, broadcast, service-discovery

Is there any way I can broadcast my computer name/location/IP and also receive their computer names via a program connected to internet without a central server at work ? [Consider this for example.Can I go without a central server.](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/napster2.htm)

[image]

There can be a central server that stores the names of all the computers who have got the application installed and are connected to internet but is there any way I can do without it ?

*To connect to remote PC I have used RMI earlier and understand what it is capable of.*

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: as @raven1981 mentioned, you can use multicast, however be aware that it comes with a variety of network "gotchas" (e.g. it is often disabled in certain scenarios or across subnets, etc.) so it may not be a very robust solution depending on your network configuration.  other than multicast, though, the answer is "no", you can't do it without some form of central server.

Comment: Totally possible, but if you plan to use this over the internet, it is far less hassle to use a centralized server to at least initiate the sessions.

Comment: @SuhailGupta, Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table